# Django default isolation level and db binary log format error

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb

I'm running a set of tests on my `django` webserver using `pytest-django`. I'm trying to switch from a MySQL database server to MariaDB in my testing/CI on travis, and for that I also switched from the `mysqldb` python package to `pymysql`.

When using MariaDB, I suddenly get a strange exception for *all* my database related tests:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1665, 'Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.')

*This exception is below in a stack of several exceptions in all tests for that job, but I've identified it as the root cause for the issue.*

It's important to note that out of the two jobs that run the test-suite directly on travis, and another that runs it on docker (inside travis), only one fails, the one running on python 3.6.

Although I *roughly* understand the cause of the problem I could not find a lot of information about the specifics or any reason for it to trigger/manifest all of a sudden. Except this [Django documentation issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28901).

Given it's only triggered for the python3 test job and Django2 dropping support for python2 I assume the issues are related but still I can't seem to figure a reasonable/decent solution. I feel I'm missing at least some of the cause/reasoning behind what's going on in here.

I didn't make any changes to database configuration and all services are running with builtin installations.

For reference, [this](https://travis-ci.org/nirizr/rematch/jobs/404939831) is a travis job for the PR, in case I missed something important out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TL;DR:* installing a more up-to-date version of MariaDB solved the issue.

Reading some more on the issue, I was able to determine the root cause was indeed due to a collision between two *default* configurations in my environment:

1. `BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT`.

   This was the default in MariaDB until version 10.2.4, according to [MariaDB's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/binary-log-formats/#statement-based). Since I was using Travis-CI and because of how [using MariaDB on travisCI was documented](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MariaDB) version 10.0 was *hardcoded*, thus defaulting to above value.
2. transaction isolation level is set to `READ COMMITTED`

   On Python3, Django>=2.0 was installed, in which transaction isolation level is set to `READ COMMITTED` according to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#default-mysql-isolation-level-is-read-committed). This configuration seems to be a safer default value.

Replacing the major/minor version string in the example travis mariadb snippet:

```
addons:
  - mariadb: '10.0'
```

With a major only version string of `'10.3'` made travis install a more up-to-date version or MariaDB, which defaulted to the more flexible `BINLOG_FORMAT = MIXED` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
# config as this way, add options
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xx',
        'HOST': 'xxx',
        'POST': 'xxx',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'isolation_level': "repeatable read"
        },
    },
}
```